# Array_in_String

Tags: php, arrays, search

I just wrote this function :

```
function Array_in_String($Haystack1, $Values1)
{
    foreach ($Values1 as $token1) 
    {
        if (strpos($Haystack1, $token1) !== false) return true;
    }
}
```

that basically searches a string `$Haystack1` for multiple values in an array `$Values1` and returns true if hits a match.

Before that, I searched a lot in PHP for a similar string function. I'm still wondering if PHP has a similar function?

Answer (score 2):

No, PHP does not have the function you need.
**EDIT**
Create your custom function if you want to use some code more than once.

Comment: _better write this in your code directly_ what if he wants to use it more than once? DRY dies right there. _Writing you own function may confuse someone_ So...never create a new function in PHP in case it confuses someone?

Comment: I still can't agree with that. _create your custom function only if you are sure you will need to do this action really often_ should quite simply be _create your custom function if you want to use it **more than once**._

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a function, but your logic can be greatly simplified by using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
function array_in_string($haystack, $needles) {
    return str_replace($needles, '', $haystack) !== $haystack;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Dzolyq)

Though, if your needle array is really huge, the code posted in your question may have a better performance as it will return `true` in the first match while my solution always iterates over all needles.

Answer (score 0):

```
return array_reduce(
  $Values1,
  function($result, $token1) use ($Haystack1) {
    return $result || strpos($Haystack1, $token1) !== false;
  }, 
  false
);
```

or

```
$matches = array_map(
  function($token1) use ($Haystack1) {
    return strpos($Haystack1, $token1) !== false;
  },
  $Values1
);
return (bool) count(array_filter($matches));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

this produces:

```
"lastname,email,phone"
```

Edit: of course you'll have to make a preg_match on this string afterwards.

Comment: @Bogdan In fact, it is. It implies *"you can then simply search the resulting string"* - only problem is that you have to choose a delimiter that is not part of any individual array value. That's what makes this approach unsuitable for a generic solution. But it would work for a specific situation, for example if it is clear that the array elements will never contain a comma.

Comment: Well, you could also use any other delimiter, like a space. but in fact that solution depends on what you want to do and is not valid for any array.